# Gattlib read_by_handle function: Where is read data stored?

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial-port, raspberry-pi3, bluez

This is my first question and I am engineer by grade, not a programmer, so please bear with me:

I am attempting to pull data from a BLE device to my raspberry pi 3. The BLE device is an HC 05 module sending out the serial data "9999" every 1 second through a simple Arduino Script.

BlueZ 5.44 appears to be configured correctly, as I can connect and disconnect without issue.

The documentation for the library in question is here: https://bitbucket.org/OscarAcena/pygattlib/overview

This is my test script:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
from gattlib import GATTRequester, GATTResponse
import time


class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
        store=''
        self.requester = GATTRequester(address, False)
        self.connect()
        self.request_data()

    def connect(self):
        print("Connecting...", end=' ')

        self.requester.connect()
        print("OK!")

    def request_data(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        data = self.requester.read_by_handle(0x5)

        print (data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: {} <addr>".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(1)

    Reader(sys.argv[1])
    print("Done.")
```

Console Output:

```
Connecting... OK!
on notification, handle: 0x12 -> 00:39:39:39:39:
on notification, handle: 0x12 -> 00:39:39:39:39:
['\x00\x00']
Done.
```

The information listed after:

```
on notification, handle: 0x12 ->
```

Is the data I am looking for. The hex equivalent of ASCII "9999".

However, that information is printed out to the console from a C file contained in the pygattlib library.

In my code, the only output I have access to is:

```
['\x00\x00']
```

Which is clearly not the data I am looking for.

So my question is: How can I obtain the desired data to a variable inside the script? I simply want to avoid having to use subprocess.Popen to obtain the console data when that seems like it should be entirely unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this device myself, and I'm just experimenting with the same API, but I think you want to register a notification handler for address 0x12 (going off your console output) instead of reading address 0x05.

Based on the example in your link it should look something like

```
from gattlib import GATTRequester, GATTResponse

class NotifyYourName(GATTResponse):
    def on_response(self, name):
        print("your name is: {}".format(name))

response = NotifyYourName()
req = GATTRequester("00:11:22:33:44:55") # use your address here
req.read_by_handle_async(0x12, response)

while True:
    # here, do other interesting things
    sleep(1)
```

The data is normally returned as a list from the `read_by_handle` method (when you're reading a register say) so you'd normally use something like `data = read_by_handle(0x05)[0]`, however I think it is different for a device that is sending notifications on it's own.